# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (495): x

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am pretty new to R, I was doing some hands-on on the titanic dataset (available online). I was trying to analyze the data. I got the below error while running the function ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Amelia)

titanic <- read.csv("D:/Data Science/Datasets-20180505T065250Z- 001/titanic.csv",
                    header=TRUE)
summary(titanic)
str(titanic)
names(titanic)
# Checking missing values (missing values or empty values)
colSums(is.na(titanic)|titanic=='')

# Explore how much missing data we have
missmap(titanic, main = "Titanic Data - Missing map", 
        col=c("yellow", "black"), legend = FALSE)

#Next step is to fill missing data
#Missing fare data imputation
#Extract the fare which contains missing data

fare_na <- dplyr::filter(titanic, is.na(titanic$fare)==TRUE|titanic$fare=='')
#fare_na <- subset(titanic,is.na(titanic$fare))
fare_na
fare_na1 <- dplyr::filter(titanic, titanic$ï..pclass==3 & titanic$embarked=="S")
fare_na1

ggplot(dplyr::filter(titanic, 
                     titanic$ï..pclass==3 & titanic$embarked=="S"), 
       aes(titanic$fare)) +
  geom_density(fill="blue", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(titanic$fare, na.rm = T)), 
             colour='darkblue', linetype='dashed',size=2) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(titanic$fare, na.rm = T)), 
             colour='red', linetype='dashed',size=2) +
  ggtitle("Fare details of 3rd class passengers \n embarked from Southampton port") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Below is the code used:

Comment: Some more effort on [formatting the question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) would be very nice.

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: Below is the error:
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (495): x